# NHibernate: Change from lazy=true to fetch=join brings back the world

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a User object/mapping in my application. Each user has a list of contact information (phone, email etc)

the mapping for the user contains:

```
<bag name="ContactInfo" table="contact_info" lazy="true" cascade="all">
    <key column="contact_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="...ContactInfo, ..."/>
</bag>
```

this works fine but i get the n+1 select problem so i need to optimize it a little bit. But for some reason, when I change this to a join and perform some db operation, NH starts updating ALL contact_info objects in the database. When i say db operation i dont mean changinf a contact. i mean anything.

Anyone knows why? thx

EDIT: Just realized that it does it for lazy="true" as well but the second time, after the objects have been loaded. the question of why remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that an enum field in ContactInfo was the problem. i didnt mind if that particular filed was a string so changing it resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if your cascades are causing the issue. Do you have cascade=all on your entire graph? If so you may want to re-evaluate your lifecycle strategy.

Here's a though from section 9.9 of NHibernate 1.2 reference (emphasis added)

> Mapping an association (many-to-one,
>   or collection) with cascade="all"
>   marks the association as a parent/
>   child style relationship where
>   save/update/deletion of the parent
>   results in save/update/deletion of the
>   child(ren). **Futhermore, a mere
>   reference to a child from a persistent
>   parent will result in save / update of
>   the child**.

Comment: but why would this happen? I am not changing anything so whats the update for?

in any case, i changed it to cascade=none and it made no difference.

thanks for your reply